# New consumer unit and MCB calculations

Tags: control, power-consumption

I am planning on running a new circuit from my current board to a new unit in the loft that I am turning into a mini studio.

I am trying to work out what Amp MCBs I would need, however am not sure I got the math right!

[image: Calculations so far]

For the ones that I have an output and volts I did Output * Volts to give watts. However that seems loads over what I had for the other laptop that had 45 on the charger. Plus, I find it hard to believe the decks have a 690 draw without any box in the way, forgive my lack of knowledge here!

I am going to be doing this wiring then getting an electrician friend of mine to actually connect it to the main unit via the MCB but he is too busy to do the whole job, so I am doing what I can with the wiring and cables. I just need to know what to buy to make sure I can do it while being safe!

Laptop: MSI PX60
Decks: Pioneer SX2
PC: Corsair rm650x
Screen: SAMSUNG C24F396 x3
Speakers: Pioneer DM40 x2
Laptop: HP Probook

Now, I was originally going to run each plug off of it's own MCB, however looking at the draw I can calculate I think I could run it off of four?

Basically, are my calculations for the breaker sizes accurate?

If not, where did I go wrong and what do I need to find out?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it’s not about electronics design and would be better on the DIY stack exchange site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a worst case load of about 3 kW. Your load will seldom, if ever, reach anywhere near that power. If it does you will have the equivalent of a 3 kW electric heater in your room and room temperature will become a problem.

From the comments:

> I like the granularity that breaking it out into different MCBs would provide.

1. There is no need for this other than fault tolerance should you have a trip. With decent quality equipment that you've got this isn't going to be a problem and I would be surprised if you had one circuit breaker trip in ten years.
2. A more likely scenario is an earth leakage (RCD/GFCI) trip and in most countries - you have no location in your user profile or question - this will be in the common path to all power circuits so you will lose the whole studio. This makes your individual circuits a probable waste of time.
3. I suspect that your local regulations will require a minimum wire cross-sectional area for a wall socket. If you have to run that then you might as well use it to capacity.

Wire it up in a standard fashion.

Answer (score 2):

I would just do a standard radial circuit with 2.5mm^2 cable and a 20A MCB.

This is the safest option as, in the future, someone else may plug in something different.

Comment: Thanks Mike!

I did debate it, however I like the granularity that breaking it out into different MCBs would provide. No one else would be plugging in anything else, as it will be a dedicated room for this and once I leave I will be taking most of what I have done with me to replicate in the next location, so I am not worried about people plugging in other devices.

With that being said, would it still be better to do it that way? Am I being stupid running it like I have said? Most importantly to me, is my math at all close?